# Front-end datagram truncation UDP Android

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp

Thanks in advance to any support,

I'm trying to broadcast a UDP message on the local network. After sending a particular string, responders send back metadata about their location, IP address, status etc.

I've gotten communication to occur, but the issue is in the string response itself.

**TLDR:** My udp receive packet is cutting off **front** elements of the datagram.

I dont think this is a buffer size issue. My buff is 2048, much larger than the data I'm looking to receive (about 50-200 characters).

I have worked with this setup before and gotten the first part no problem (with iOS). A wireshark (equivalent) console also confirms. Wireshark and Android output have been attached for comparison.

[Proper data coming in via packet app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCWya.png)

[Front-truncated packet in logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyiN9.png) (notice that everything up until "[Red]" has been omitted)

inside onCreate:

```
try{
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    socket.setBroadcast(true);
    socket.setSoTimeout(3000);
    broadcastPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                broadcastString.getBytes(),
                broadcastString.length(),
                getBroadcastAddress(),
                30303);
}catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("MYAPP", "socket error", e);
}
```

inside an AsyncTask:

```
try {
    while(true) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(receivePacket);
        String receiveString = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength() );
        Log.d("a", "Received response " + receiveString );
        Log.d("a", "From host " + receivePacket.getAddress() );
        Log.d("a", "With offset " + receivePacket.getOffset() );
    }
}catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    Log.d("a", "Receive timed out");
}
```

note that before using receivePacket.getLength() I'd just get a bunch of ?'s *after* the partial response

Comment: SHow us your code.  My bet is you're using some sort of readline and cutting everything off except the last line yourself-  notice how you just happened to start after the last newline.

Comment: 'My udp receive packet is cutting off front elements of the datagram' I would bet my film collection that you are wrong and your own code/data is just screwed up.

Comment: @MartinJames, got any good movies in there?

Comment: @SergeyA I have DVD's etc going back decades and some 'real reel'.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the comment. I included the correct data that returns via wireshark with the same discovery string, broadcast IP and port. I have made this work on iOS. If my code is wrong, would you be so kind as to submit a solution?

Comment: @GabeSechan that's what I was thinking since the cutoff point is consistent. However, after combing through the DatagramSocket class and documentation I couldn't find any settings that mention any sort of character-keyed truncation. Have you heard of anything of that nature in this context?

Comment: There is no such thing. Of course. UDP datagrams are received entire and intact or not at all.

Comment: @EJP this I understand, and is the reason I'm being thrown off--take a look at the posted links which show the difference between the expected full packet and what I'm getting in logcat. Same process, same network, same everything. My suspicion is that the object has a feature that truncates starting at a character key like \r\n, which I would think would be useful in certain situations, but I have been unable to find any reference to such a feature, and thought perhaps a Java expert can point me in the right direction.

Comment: For the second time, there is no such feature.

Comment: @EJP thank you. I will move forward assuming my data is there and that it is an IDE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did end up being an Android Studio bug.

```
String[] deviceElements = receiveString.split("\r\n");
Log.d("a", deviceElements[0]);
```

returned the data I was looking for; intially printing the full receiveString returned only a portion of the string.